# Cythonize function includes root folder in extension name

Tags: cython, cythonize

### The Problem

I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
\t_src
    \mylib
        __init__.py
        module.pyx
        (... other .py sources)
setup.py
(other non .py files)
```

my `setup.py` uses `cythonize` to compile the `.pyx` file:

```
setup(
    (...)
    ext_modules=cythonize(['mylib/**/*.pyx'])
    (...)
)
```

It mostly works but when I create a binary wheel (using `python setup.py build_ext bdist_wheel clean --all`), my wheel file has this structure:

```
\mylib
    (all python modules)
\t_src
    \mylib
        (compiled cython modules)
```

Which is not good as I would expect to have the compiled cython modules also inside the `mylib` root folder.

### Possible cause

Investigating a bit, it appears that the problem is on the extension names generated from the `cythonize()` function, which all begin with `t_src`, like:

```
t_src.mylib.module1
```

### Workaround

If I actually run the `cythonize()` function before the `setup()` function and manually strip out the `"t_src."` string from Extension names, then my wheel has everything inside `mylib` as expected:

```
ext_modules=cythonize(['mylib/**/*.pyx'])

for module in ext_modules:
    module.name = module.name.replace("t_src.","")

setup(
    (...)
    ext_modules=ext_modules
    (...)
)
```

Is this expected behavior somehow or am I doing something wrong? What could be causing this? For now this workaround will do but I would like to know the proper way of approaching this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I basically changed the structure of my project to:

```
\t_src
    \src
        \mylib
            (files)
    \tests
        (files)
    setup.py
    (other files)
```

And added this to my `setup.py`:

```
packages=find_packages('src'),
package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

Then I had no more problems and cythonized modules were placed on the `mylib` folder together with other python files, just as it was supposed to.

I actually changed the layout after realizing that my tests used the code on the current folder instead of the installed package. Lucky I was that this also solved the problem stated on this question.

Answer (score 0):

check this out: https://groups.google.com/g/cython-users/c/d-3Clm2EkHs

Likely your root directory includes a `__init__.py`. That makes it a python module. Removing that file should fix your issue.